# Gridview asp.net cancel edit mode pressing ESC

Tags: gridview, escaping

I just want to know what is the easiest way to cancel the edit mode on a gridView after pressiong the Esc key.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I don´t pretend this solution is good, but you could use jQuery and a hidden cancel button:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(this).keypress(function(e) {

            if (e.keyCode == 27) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#<%= cancelButton.ClientID  %>').click();
            }
        });
    });
```

which only means that when the user clicks escape, the hidden button is clicked.

```
<div style="display:none">
  <asp:Button runat="server" ID="cancelButton" OnClick="CancelButton_Click"/>
</div>
```

In the Click-Event of the button, you cancel the edit mode (given the GridView has ID="grid"):

```
protected void CancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (grid.EditIndex != -1)
    {
        grid.EditIndex = -1;
        grid.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I don´t know how to access the cancel button in the gridview row directly.